# change DOM while heavy function is running

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom, ecmascript-6

I want to display a loading-spinner [like this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp) while a heavy function is blocking the main thread.

My code basically looks like this:

```
image.onload = function onLoad() {
  document.getElementById("loading-spinner").style.display = "block";
  run_heavy_function(this);
};
```

The loading spinner is only showing up after the function is done. Which is not what i want.

I've come across some solutions using setTimeout and stuff. But that doesn't seem like a good idea to me. What is the right approach to change the DOM in a background process in ES6 using pure javascript?

Comment: The solution is to don't block the main thread. You might want to use web workers for heavy tasks, if you can use them (due to support). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy pattern to solve this is event comunication:

```
const loaderStart = new Event('loaderStart');
const loaderEnd = new Event('loaderEnd');
const spinner = document.getElementById("loading-spinner");

image.onload = function onLoad() {
  spinner.dispatchEvent(loaderStart);
  run_heavy_function(this);
  spinner.dispatchEvent(loaderEnd);
};

spinner.addEventListener('loaderStart', function(){
   this.style.display = "block";
});

spinner.addEventListener('loaderEnd', function(){
   this.style.display = "none";
});
```